# Configure custom DATETIME conversion for Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, datetime, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, date-formatting

Doctrine returns dates like...

```
{
    "date": "2014-03-26 20:05:13",
    "timezone_type": 3,
    "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

...by default.

Is there a way to **configure** it (at the highest possible level) to return (and accept) formatted strings like...

```
2014-03-26 20:05:13 +0000
```

...or any other RFC or custom date format?

I'd prefer configuration solutions over custom hydrators / classes / etc.

Comment: check : http://www.daredevel.com/working-with-datetime-in-doctrine2-and-zend-framework-2/